# What is the union of all the tangent plane at every point of a sphere?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $S = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3: ||x||_2 = 1\}$

Then pick a point on $S$.

The tangent space to the point is the plane that is perpendicular to the vector from origin to that point.

[image]

What is the union of all these planes for all the points on $S$?

Comment: I find it remarkable that you had to ask the question after producing that lovely graphic. Just roll the sphere in the graphic around and you have your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s $\left\{x\in\Bbb R^3:\|x\|_2\ge 1\right\}$. It’s clear that the set in question includes $S$ itself. If $\|x\|_2>1$, let $P$ be any plane that contains $x$ and the origin. $S\cap P$ is a great circle on $S$, and it should be clear that there are two lines through $x$ that are tangent to that circle. Let $y$ be one of the points of tangency; then the tangent plane to $S$ at $y$ contains $x$.

Comment: +1. This describes the tangent bundle of $\Bbb S^n$ too, no?

Comment: @Ivo: I hadn’t thought about it, but it certainly seems to do so.

Comment: Brian's answer to the question is correct, but the union of these tangent hyperplanes is not the total space of the tangent bundle of $\Bbb{S}^n$.

Comment: Thee tangent spaces to different points are disjoint inthe tangent bundle, by definition.

Answer (score 1):

If $S$ is any convex smooth solid,
the union of all the
tangent planes to $S$
is  all of space
except for the
interior of $S$.

For any point P outside of $S$,
the set of lines through $P$
tangent to $S$
form a generalized cone.
To find one of these lines
(which is all you need),
find the two points on $S$
closest and farthest
from $P$.
By continuity,
the tangent planes
at these points are
perpendicular to the lines
from $P$ to the points.
Now,
rotate one of the tangent planes
until it coincides with the other plane,
keeping tangent to $S$.
At the start,
$P$ is on one side of the plane,
and, at the end,
$P$ is on the other side of the plane.
Therefore,
somewhere in between,
the plane passed through $P$.

Anyway,
this satisfies me,
but please do not
ask me to make it rigorous.
My differential geometry days
are long gone and forgotten.